# Substitute a tag for another while keeping its content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Some markup content uses `<span class='i'>` and I want to replace those with `<i>`. I came up with this clumsy solution:

```
markup = '<div>abdef<span class="i">xyz<b>012</b>pqr</span>trs</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'i'}):
    i.wrap(soup.new_tag("i"))
    i.unwrap()
```

Can this be improved? I would imagine there is a simpler way to deal with such a common task.

Answer (score 0):

Uring `.replace()` in python:

```
markup = markup.replace('<span class="i">', '<i>')
```

will work for any string. This does not use beautifulsoup however. This is also assuming you only want `<span class="i">` replaced and it stays constant throughout the string.

Comment: And removing the `</span>` with a more complicated regex and using `re.sub`. I got that. I am more interested about a BeautifulSoup answer if it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename the tag and clear the attributes:

```py
for i in soup.select("span.i"):
    i.name, i.attrs = "i", {}

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<div>abdef<i>xyz<b>012</b>pqr</i>trs</div>
```